# Need to tunnel a AWS server using port forwarding

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel

I am having a AWS server and I am connecting through a AWS router.  I gave the example here,

```
ssh -i ~/ecserver.pem ec2-user@ip -p 2222
```

Now I have to create a tunnel to the server for 9093 port in my PC.  Please help me for that,

```
ssh -f -N -L 9093:localhost:9093 -i ~/ecserver.pem ec2-user@ip -p 2222
```

Comment: Check [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work/118650#118650) and update what do you really want to achieve.